# Bash shell "Join" command not identifying operands

Tags: linux, bash, shell, syntax-error, gedit

I have bash version 4.3.8(1) running in my system:

I am trying to convert the "smb-shared" path to directory to "run/gvfs/1000.." path respectively through bash script in Gedit editor.

Code in the link is my code which runs fine for local path but gives error for "samba shared": 
https://github.com/VIVEKLUCKY1848/ubuntu_editors/blob/master/gedit_test.sh

I am getting error `join: missing operand after ‘/’` even if I remove quotes around / in the join call.

Can somebody help me out here to make this script working ?

Comment: there are several problems in your script, but the one causing your error message is that the function `join` is being declared too late. You must place the definition before its call. usually functions are placed at the start of a script. The join command you are executing is the one in `/bin/join`.

Answer (score 0):

At the point where you call `join` you haven't defined it yet.  So instead the shell uses `/usr/bin/join`.  Define `join` at the top of the script.  And ideally rename it to something else to avoid confusion.

The script runs fine for local paths because it doesn't really do anything for local paths, in particular is never calls `join`.